# What might be meant by $\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What might be meant by $\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$?

I do not know what this notation means-

Answer (score 5):

In general $A^B$ is used to denote the set of functions $B \rightarrow A$.

Hence in your case, $$\{ 0, 1,2 \}^{\mathbb{Z}} = \{ f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{ 0, 1, 2 \} \}$$ This set can also be thought of as 'sequences' indexed by all integers (positive, zero and negative) of $0, 1$ and $2$.

Comment: Surely these are not sequences with the usual meaning, since the indices can be negative. A sequence is a function on $\mathbb{N}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Fair point; I'll clarify.

Comment: I was just struck by two people giving the same inaccurate answer. Still, isn't a sequence by definition a function on the naturals? I don't know if there's a name for a function on the integers.

Comment: Yes usually. But any index set will do. I've now put sequences in quotes. I hope that will appease your puritanical heart. ;-)

Comment: That set should be written as $\{f \mid f : \Bbb Z \to \{0,1,2\}\}$.

Comment: @SimonS Pedagogical yes, Puritanical no :-)

Comment: I would be reluctant to make a categorical statement about sequences that had their historical origins in the realm of the natural numbers -- e.g., the Fibonacci sequence. One can work backwards in the Fibonaccis and arrive at an extension of the series that has most of the same mathematical characteristics of the original but will still be useless for enumerating the members of, say, a new generation of rabbits.

Answer (score 2):

This is the collection of sequences $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ for which each term $a_n$ is one of $0$,$1$, or $2$.

Comment: Surely these are not sequences with the usual meaning, since the indices can be negative. A sequence is a function on $\mathbb{N}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's not uncommon to talk about sequences in that context. The important feature is that they are indexed by a countably infinite set.

Comment: You are right, though, strictly speaking it isn't a sequence in normal sense.